# Responsive works on Iphone, but not on Samsung-phones

Tags: android, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

```
/* CSS Dokument */
body{
        background-image: url('baggrund.jpg') !important;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #464646;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    body{
        background-image: url('baggrund.jpg') !important;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #464646;
    }
}
```

I have added the above code to my CSS document and with the help from bootstrap my website will be responsive.

But the funny thing is, that my responsive works fine on iPhone, but not on Samsung (Tried on S3/S5 mini).

I'm really glad for this simple solution, so I would like to keep it this way.

Mobiletest.me doesn't show a correct screen. It's otherwise when you are doing it physically.

My website is: http://odsgaardklausen.dk/DBS/DBS.php

Comment: You define a body  style for "@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) ", but there is no difference with original body style. Why?

Comment: Oh. I think that was a mistake. Thank you :-) I solved the problem myself by adding: html {min-height:100%;} to the CSS :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself by adding to the CSS :

```
html {min-height:100%;}
```